# How can I delete a graph in the smallest number of steps?

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, graph-theory, theory

Given a directed graph, how can I find the order needed to delete the smallest number of nodes in order to delete the entire graph? I'm assuming that if a node is deleted, all outer nodes (of any degree) connected to it are deleted as well.

For example, in a binary search tree, the fastest way to delete all nodes in the tree (given the assumption) would be to delete the root node. However, given any graph, how can one figure out which nodes to delete?

**What I have in mind (pretty slow):**

1. Generate all possible subgraphs and find the subgraph with the most outer edges.
2. Delete that subgraph.
3. Repeat until there are no more remaining nodes.

**Why it's a good question:** 
Suppose we were given a directed graph with nodes that represent all the problems in the world, and all these nodes were connected with edges that represented causes/effects (i.e. some problems cause others). How can we find the smallest number of problems to get rid of in order to get rid of all problems?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's pretty obvious from the copy/paste nature of your question that it's an assignment question. We don't mind helping with those but the way it's formatted at the moment is a "do it for me" which we're not here to do. If we were, we'd get the degree at the end ;). Update you question with some examples of what you've tried and we'll help if we can.

Comment: I have added my answer to this problem, but I have to admit that it's a pretty slow algorithm. Also, keep in mind that this isn't an assignment question. I'm just wondering if anyone can come up with a better way of solving this problem.

Comment: Much better. You'll receive a decent response now.

Comment: So, if you delete a node, you delete every node it points to, every node those nodes point to, and so on.  Also, it’s a graph and not a tree.  Given that, when can you say, “It would be better to delete that node than this one, because if I delete that one, I’ll zap both nodes and maybe some others?”

Comment: you need to figure out how many nodes you can reach from every node of the graph. in order to do that, you need to perform a graph traversal (bfs/dfs) starting from every node. after you find the start node with maximum number of reachable nodes, you remove it, and all its "reachable" nodes, then repeat the procedure, until no nodes left

Comment: What is the max number of nodes in your question?

Comment: @MicoAbrina Could you unaccept my answer, please? I'd like to delete it. My algorithm is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

A vertex can have either:

1. No connected edges or outbound connected edges only (i.e. the first vertex of a path);
2. Inbound connected edges only (i.e. the last vertex of a path); or
3. Both inbound and outbound connected edges - in which case it is either:

   1. Part of a [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_components) (SCC) - i.e. a cycle `a->b->c->a` or vertices with connecting edges in both directions `a->b->c + c->b->a`; or
   2. Part of a directed acyclic sub-graph - i.e. `b` in a simple path `a->b->c` or in a set of branching paths `a->b->c + b->d->e + f->b`.

Vertices matching case (1) can be trivially searched for and deleted - the vertices with no inbound edges cannot be deleted by deleting any other vertex so must be contained within the set of minimal vertices required to delete the graph.

Vertices matching cases (2) and (3.2) can be ignored; deleting the vertex at the head of the path will delete all vertices in the middle of the path (case 3.2) and at the end of the path (case 2) so these vertices will never be included within the set of minimal vertices required to delete the graph.

Deleting any vertex contained in a SCC (case 3.1) will delete all vertices in the SCC (and all descendant sub-trees branching from the SCC). The graph can be (trivially) reduced by collapsing a SCC to a single pseudo-vertex (where all edges connected to vertices contained in the SCC are instead considered to be connected, with the same directionality, to the pseudo-vertex); repeating this for all SCCs will reduce the graph to set of connected directed acyclic graphs (DAG).

Each DAG will have one-or-more root vertices (with no outbound edges) which will either be actual vertices, of case (1), or pseudo-vertices, representing case (3.1). The minimal deletion set is this set of root vertices - i.e. all root vertices of case (1) and for each root pseudo-vertex (representing case 3.1) any one actual vertex contained within that SCC.

Stronly connected components can be found using [Tarjan's Strongly Connected Components Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%E2%80%99s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) and once reduced to a DAG the root vertices can be found by counting inbound edges.

The order in which these vertices are deleted is not important - deleting any one of these vertices will not delete any of the others in the minimal deletion set so they can be deleted in any order and have to all be deleted to delete the entire graph. (The vertices in the minimal deletion set may share some or all of their descendants and the order of deletion would affect the order in which these descendants are removed but this is not asked about in the question.)